# jQuery find element with class name and attribute value

Tags: jquery

Haven't come up with much as far as documentation goes.  How do I find an element with a particular class name that also has a specified attribute value.?

```
function go_to_page(page){
    $('.page_link[longdesc=page]').addClass('.active_page'); 
}
```

I got the example from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_end_value.asp).  Tried testing it myself and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function go_to_page(page){

    $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page + ']').addClass('active_page'); 

}
```

Comment: We all have our moments ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your syntax, try:

```
 function go_to_page(page){

     $('.page_link[longdesc='+page+']').addClass('active_page'); 
 }
```

classes normally don't start with a dot (only in the selector not the name)